Can I convert a .txt list of references in IEEE format to Harvard format?
I have a long list of references (about 120 of them) in IEEE format. It's just a plain old .txt file. I would like to convert them all at once to Harvard style references. Is there a software or a website that can do something like that?
Thank you.

How similar are the items in your list? If very similar, write a regex to capture its elements in an array and then output them in the appropriate format and order. If very unsimilar, you'll be quicker to do it by hand. It'll be an afternoon's work. —— If every source has a DOI, you can use a citation manager (e.g. Mendeley, Zotero, Citavi) to grab the info for each DOI from the web and output the bibliographic information in whatever format you want.

You could try using a citation manager to import and then export in the correct folder, but it's a while since I've used any so I can't give an up to date recommendation. Otherwise, it might be quicker to format 120 by hand if you consider the time to find, download, familiarize yourself with, and run software.

Can you say how that's about Writing, rather than data processing

It fits perfectly with the tags "citations" and "software" that I added, but thank you for your concern. And much thanks to other answers that were helpful :)
